# CSV file data insert into the database

Tags: php, csv

I am using below code for insert csv file data in to the database,Data has to be insert in to the database but while loop can't control end of file that mean only 1 records in that file(column name is also there) but while loop loop 2 times second time email sent to the email

```
define('csv','C:/wamp/www/csvfile/');

$csv_file = "csv/Customer.csv";     

$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');

$theData = fgets($csvfile);

$i = 0;

if(file_exists("csv/Customer.csv")) {

        while(!feof($csvfile)) {

            $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);

            $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);   

            if($csv_array[0] != '' AND $csv_array[1] != '' AND $csv_array[2] != '' AND $csv_array[3] != ''){        

                $insert_offline_cust = "insert into Registration(CustomerID,name,CustType,Status) values ('".$csv_array[0]."','".$csv_array[1]."',,'".$csv_array[2]."','".$csv_array[3]."')";       

                mssql_query($insert_offline_cust)  or die("Insert Error"); 

                $i++;                                                                           

            }else{              
                $to = "abc@gmail.com";      
                    $subject = "CSV file data";
                        $message = "Some value missing<br>";                                                            
                        $headers = "From: XYZ" . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

                    //echo $message;exit;   

                    // send mail to customer.
                    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
                    $i++;                   
            }

        }
        fclose($csvfile);
```

Comment: *cough* `LOAD DATA INFILE` *cough*

Answer (score 0):

HERE YOU GO :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>INPUT CSV FILE</title>
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>
<form action="1.php" method="post" name="frmcsv" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><input type="file" name="csv"/></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND"/></p>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $filename=$_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
    $type=$_FILES['csv']['type'];
    if($type=='application/vnd.ms-excel'){
        $fop=fopen($filename,"r");
        while(($file=fgetcsv($fop,1000,","))!==false)
    {
        echo $file[0].','.$file[1].','.$file[2].','.$file[3].','.$file[4].'<br/>';

    }
    fclose($fop);
    }
    else{
        echo'NOT CORRECT FORMAT';   
    }
}
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

After echo your file contents , you can INSERT into your data base and then send your mail .

Comment: One think is how to send missing column data vie email

Comment: what did you mean 'missing column data' ? you mean php can not insert data in database?

Comment: if($file[0] != '' AND $file[1] != '' AND $file[2] != '' AND $file[3] != '') In CSV file data are required if some column data is not there then send those row vie email

Comment: I mean all CSV file column data are required if something missing in that file then sent only those row vie email.

Comment: But i wnat those whole records

Comment: use`&&` between your statements

Comment: i got it ans $csv_array[0]